# Can't get Instantiate working

Tags: unity, instancing

I am building a 2D game and I want to fire a bullet from my player whenever the player press certain button. But, When I use instantiate and add force to my rigidbody it won't work.
The code is: -

```
    public bool hit;
    public Rigidbody2D gun;
    public float count;
    public Transform pos;
    public Collision2D col;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        hit = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "firePotion") {
            hit = true;
        }
    }
    void Update () {
        if (hit = true && Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {
            Rigidbody2D gunPrefab;
            gunPrefab = Instantiate (gun, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody2D;
            gunPrefab.AddForce (-pos.forward * 5000);
        }
        OnCollisionEnter2D (col);
    }
}
```

Here, I am trying to make the player able to shoot whenever he takes a potion. But, Neither the onCollision2D is working nor the AddForce. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I noticed a few things:

```
if (hit = true && Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1"))
```

this will actually set `hit` *to* true every time! If you want to check if `hit` *is* true use `hit == true` or even better just `hit` (because `hit` is already a true/false value).

When you instantiate your `gunPrefab` you don't set the tag on the gameobject as "firePotion" so when you go into the `OnCollision2D` the thing you're supposedly colliding with doesn't have the tag and therefore doesn't make it though your if statement.

`col` is never initialised. If your going to call `OnCollision2D` explicitly as you are now you need to make sure that the `col` object actually exists, otherwise when you reach  `col.gameObject.tag` in the collision method you can't actually get the gameobject because `col` is null and doesn't actually have any data and will just create a `NullReferenceException`!

---

I'd recommend attaching a debugger and just stepping though the code line by line to see what it actually does. If you can see the data changing it makes it a lot easier to understand what is going wrong. All IDEs worth your time will be able to do this.

Hope this helped

Comment: Thanks. But, Why is the add force not working?

Comment: `forward` in Unity points along the local z axis, but 2D physics happen in the xy plane. So unless you've rotated `pos`, the force you're applying may have no projection on the physics plane.